# Is it possible to use an assert or a raise in a conditional expression?

Tags: python

I want to use a conditional expression as follows:

```
young_animal = 'puppy' if animal == 'dog' else ('kitten' if animal == 'cat' else (assert False))
```

i.e., I only expect `animal` to be `dog` or `cat`, but I want to assert this in my code.

This is not valid python because `assert` is a statement, and not an expression. Similarly, `raise` is also a statement. What would be the best way to do this? I could of course do something as follows:

```
assert animal in ['dog', 'cat']
young_animal = 'puppy' if animal == 'dog' else 'kitten'
```

But this seems both less idiomatic, and also less safe (e.g., the lines might get separated in a refactor).

Comment: `assert`s are bad if you are writing production code, because they can be optimised out of the execution path using `python -O myfile.py` from the command line.  You are safer raising exceptions if your conditions are not met.

Comment: you could replace `assert` with an exception (e.g. `next(iter([]))` or `0/0`) but what you should really do is just write this on multiple lines in the normal readable way with if-elif-else etc.